# Different results between date and Cast As Date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, casting

I'm new to the T-SQl world and this issue is puzzling me.

I'm running a query against a variable I have created which holds the date of the start of my financial year, which is 2014-04-01. The data I'm querying against holds the date as a date time field, so I have been using CAST AS DATE to remove the timestamp.

If I run this query in this fashion I receive 25 results:

```
select      count(B.WorkOrderNumber) as AWOCount
from        TSP1_Dev.AssetDataPortal.EllipseSiteList A left outer join
            TSP1_Dev.AssetDataPortal.tblWorkOrdersActive B
on          A.EquipmentLocation = B.EquipmentLocation   
where       
            B.EquipmentLocation = 'BISHT'

            and A.EquipmentClass = 'SW'
            and right(rtrim(A.EquipmentDesc),4) = '(OU)'
            and cast(B.CreationDate as Date) >= '2014-04-01';
```

However, on one occasion I forgot to cast the date, and when I did that I received 32 results:

```
select      count(B.WorkOrderNumber) as AWOCount
from        TSP1_Dev.AssetDataPortal.EllipseSiteList A left outer join
            TSP1_Dev.AssetDataPortal.tblWorkOrdersActive B
on          A.EquipmentLocation = B.EquipmentLocation   
where       
            B.EquipmentLocation = 'BISHT'

            and A.EquipmentClass = 'SW'
            and right(rtrim(A.EquipmentDesc),4) = '(OU)'
            and B.CreationDate >= '2014-04-01';
```

Can someone please tell me why? Apologies for my ignorance!
Neil

Comment: You said you used a variable but your queries uses a string literal `2014-04-01`. If you actually used a variable, what data type was the variable declared as and what data type is `CreationDate`. And what is your `dateformat` setting for your sessions? `select date_format from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id = @@spid`

Comment: Hi there,I'm using Coldfusion to create my variable, using its CreateDate function:<cfset FYStart=CreateDate(year(now()),4,1)>. Running the code you added returns dmy.

Answer (score 1):

In the query you have string literals and from your comment I can only assume that it is Coldfusion that insert the string literal in your query. (I know nothing about Coldfusion but is there no way to use parameters instead?).

In SQL Server there is a setting for the order of date parts in strings. [SET DATEFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

What you see can be reproduced if you have the date format `dmy`.

The string literal `2014-04-01` is interpreted as `yyyy-dd-mm` when compared against a `datetime`. When the new data types `date` and `datetime2` was added that behaviour was changed so string literal on the form `yyyy-mm-dd` will always be interpreted as just that regardless of `set dateformat`.

So when you cast to `date` the string literal is converted to the date `2014-04-01` but when you compare against a `datetime` the string literal is converted to `2014-01-04`.

```
set dateformat dmy;

declare @T table(D datetime);

insert into @T(D) values
('20140101'),('20140201'),
('20140301'),('20140401'),
('20140501'),('20140601');

select count(*)
from @T
where D >= '2014-04-01';

select count(*)
from @T
where cast(D as date) >= '2014-04-01';
```

Result:

```
5

3
```

One way to avoid the problem for `datetime` is to use a string literal without dashes. `20140401` will be interpreted as `yyyymmdd` regardless of `set dateformat`.

Comment: To be fair Coldfusion is creating the correct variable of 2014041 - it was me adding in the string literal as I thought i was replicating the same variable, where clearly i haven't! My ignorance in this things. Thank you for your post which makes it all much clearer.